# Wordpress blank edit page

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress shows blank page when I try to edit a page or a post.

Console shows 
$ Not a function error in some Gutenberg

I did google this and I found people running into the same issue, however I could not find any fix

Comment: Revert to the default theme and deactivate plugins until you find the one that is the culprit. If it's an issue with the theme or with a page builder plugin then you may have to install the "classic editor" plugin instead of using Gutenberg.

Answer (score 1):

I did run into the same issue when I used a theme that has the "Zion builder" as the main editor, I could not use the Wordpress editor, only the "edit with Zion builder".

The issue was fixed when I installed this plugin "Gutenberg Block addons"
https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-addons-for-gutenberg/

Comment: installing the plugin did resolve the issue on wordpress v 5.3.2. Thanks for quick answer